# How select an item from dropdown list in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-model

How select an item from dropdown list in angularjs,Here I am using normal select list but not from object array.

If I am using ng-repeat then I can select one,

but here how can I do the same?

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="range" ng-change="updateRange()">
        <optgroup label="Current">
            <option value="1.1">Today</option>
            <option value="1.2">This Week</option>
            <option value="1.3">This Month</option>
            <option value="1.4">This Quarter</option>
            <option value="1.5">This Year</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Previous">
            <option value="2.1">Yesterday</option>
            <option value="2.2">Previous Week</option>
            <option value="2.3">Previous Month</option>
            <option value="2.4">Previous Quarter</option>
            <option value="2.5">Previous Year</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup  label="Custom">
            <option ng-value="3">Custom</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
```

Comment: @maurcy it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply assign value to the model that corresponds with `option` value

http://plnkr.co/edit/bB4Y8aOufk9UL3oRRHD7?p=preview

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.range = 2.4
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your model data in form of an array :

**In your controller**

```
$scope.ModelValues = JSONResponse;
```

JSON Response should contain the value to be selected in the drop down i.e

`JSONResponse = {"range" : "100"}`

**html:**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="ModelValues.range" ng-change="updateRange()">
</select >
```

Comment: use need ng-options if you have the values in your JSON Response or hard code as you did.

Comment: ok. great but you may feel my approach better when doing actual two way data binding for the whole page!

Comment: and how exactly he loses two-way data binding with use of model?

Comment: How would you do two way binding if you get single JSON response for all field on the screen. Would you assign each and every variable in $scope one by one?

Comment: I think you are missing the point, the question was about selecting an option in select and you do that the way I did in my answer, obviously when you receive json you assign it to single model if you have to use it in partial

Comment: I did not say your solution is not correct but that is the basic way to do this and yes I posted my answer before you :)